Reflection on View
I am quite new to dremio and currently trying to work with reflections, that self-update.
For my use-case, I can´t use reflections on a table, because the available reflection-aggregations are not what I am looking for.
Now I have seen that you can add a reflection on a view. My idea is to create a view that aggregates my data, and add a pre-computing reflection on it. But there is no update-reflection-option.
Does the reflection update every time, that the table is altered? Because I am adding data to the table every few minutes.
Thanks!

Regarding your question, reflections in Dremio do update automatically when the underlying table changes. This is because reflections are designed to provide fast query performance by pre-computing and storing the results of complex queries.
When you create a reflection on a view, Dremio will automatically update the reflection whenever the underlying data in the view changes. This means that if you're adding data to the table every few minutes, the reflection will be updated accordingly.
However, it's essential to note that the update frequency depends on the reflection's refresh policy. By default, Dremio uses an incremental refresh policy, which updates the reflection only when new data is added to the table. This approach minimizes the overhead of updating the reflection.
If you need more control over the update frequency, you can adjust the reflection's refresh policy to suit your requirements. For example, you can set a schedule-based refresh policy to update the reflection at specific intervals.
To summarize:
Reflections in Dremio update automatically when the underlying table changes.
The update frequency depends on the reflection's refresh policy.
You can adjust the refresh policy to control how often the reflection is updated.

Thank you! That already helped me a lot. Can you please tell me how to change the reflection´s refresh policy? There is no option in the GUI, as far as I can tell.
